# How to put absolute element between two CSS Grid cells

Tags: css

I'm trying to put an element with `position: absolute` between two grid cells. I want half of the element to be on sidebar and half of it on the rest of the page. However, because I have `overflow` on both (sidebar & page), the element gets cropped!

What should I do?

```js
var sidebar = document.getElementById("side")

function toggleSidebar() {
  sidebar.style.width == "120px" ? sidebar.style.width = "80px" : sidebar.style.width = "120px";
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.sidebar,
.page {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: auto; /* this is causing the problem */
}

.layout {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
}

.sidebar {
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: hidden; /* this is causing the problem */
  width: 80px;
  background: orange;
  transition: width 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.page {
  background: brown;
}

.element {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  right: -70px;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  top: 80px;
  display: block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 40px;
  z-index: 100; /* doesn't work */
}
```

```html
<div class="layout">
  <div class="sidebar" id="side">
    Hi
    <div class="element" onclick="toggleSidebar()">BYE</div>
  </div>
  <div class="page">
    Hello
  </div>
  <div>
```

Comment: and you are setting overflow? keep it visible

Answer (score 0):

Since we know the size of a column I would detach it from its parent and use the container as the relative positioning container instead. Then apply a -50% `transform` to it so it's ensured to be centered regardless of the width of the `.element` is. See example below.

```js
var sidebar = document.getElementById("side");

function toggleSidebar() {
  sidebar.style.width == "120px" ? sidebar.style.width = "80px" : sidebar.style.width = "120px";
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.sidebar,
.page {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: auto; /* this is causing the problem */
}

.layout {
  display: flex;
}

.sidebar {
  overflow-x: hidden; /* this is causing the problem */
  width: 80px;
  background: orange;
  transition: width 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.page {
  background: brown;
  flex: 1;
}

#separator {
  width: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.element {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 80px;
  display: block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 0 -40px;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="layout">
  <div class="sidebar" id="side">
    Hi
  </div>
  <div id="separator">
    <div id="toggle-btn" class="element" onclick="toggleSidebar()">BYE</div>
  </div>
  <div class="page">
    Hello
  </div>
<div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, but I want the element to move with the sidebar.

Comment: @Shahriar ah ok, sorry I probably should have paid more attention. See updated answer for your intended result, I did convert from grid to flex though so let me know if grid is an actual requirement. Cheers.